# How to typeset space between number and degree celsius in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I would like to change the way `siuntix` displays the `\celsius` so that there is a space between the numerical value and the degree celsius symbol. This is what is recommended by [BIPM](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3-3.html). I have tried the following approach based on other questions on here. However, this results the degree symbol to completely disappear and I am not sure why. I am using overleaf platform. How would I change that to show e.g. **55 °C**?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
 math-celsius = \textdegree \text{C}, % for temperatures
 text-celsius = \textdegree \text{C},
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome. Isn't that the default behaviour of `$\SI{1}{\degreeCelsius}$`? I get a space at least.

Comment: What's wrong with the standard definition of `\celsius`?

Comment: You might also try `\textcelsius`, from either `fontspec` (in the modern toolchain) or `textcomp` (for backward-compatibility).

Comment: \sounits\  inserts  a thin unbreakable space between numbers and units, but you have to use the command, say; \SI{18}[\celsius}`.

Comment: Hi, please see the answer below for the difference in the spacing between number and degree symbol. The standard definition is not compatible with the National Institute of Standards and Technology(NIST) standard.

Comment: @user180025 Are you perhaps meaning that `siunitx` as-standard uses a thin space rather than a full-width space between numbers and units? That comes about as the BIPM standard talks purely about a 'space' without specifying the typography, and tradition in the latter is to have a thin space here. If you want to alter the spacing, I would do it for all units.

Comment: @user180025 The spacing used by `siunitx` is the same for all units: perhaps in your examples you are seeing TeX stretching/shrinking whitespace ...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for clarifying and the awesome package @JosephWright. Sorry I accidentally deleted my comment. New to this website.

Comment: @JosephWright that seems imprecise, `siunitx` doesn't use a space for `\degree`/`\ang` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change it with `\DeclareSIUnit`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {~}]\celsius{\SIUnitSymbolCelsius}

\begin{document}
\SI{45}{\celsius}
\end{document}
```

The package's default however is a half/thin space. Compare:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
%\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {~}]\celsius{\SIUnitSymbolCelsius}

\begin{document}
\SI{45}{\celsius}\par
\SI{45}{\degree}\par
\end{document}
```

Without the redeclaration on the left and with it on the right:

[image: without]
[image: with]

Comment: @user180025 on this site we usually say thank you by upvoting and not via comment. Also you might consider to accept an answer if it completely solves your (original) question. You should do so not immediately for the first answer but after a reasonable time period. If you get more than one answers you should accept the one you deem best (provided it solves your question in some way, of course).

Comment: I cant upvote yet lol. First thing I tried

Comment: @user180025 funny. I don't remember when you get which privilege, but not being able to upvote an answer to ones own question is strange...

Comment: I get this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @user180025 - You've got 16 rep points by now -- enough for an upvote. Plus, if you believe that Skillmon's answer has fully addressed your query, you could (should!) click on the 'checkmark' to formally "accept" this answer.